# JTABLE: CTRL + ENTER to enter same data of the editing row in the selected row

Tags: java, jtable

As you can see in the title I'm interested in enter same data of the editing row in the selected row by pressing CTRL + ENTER as in Microsoft Excel.

I tried with this code but it didn't work.(The data in the cell's table must be Object)

Could you please tell me what is wrong in the following code please?

```
InputMap  im = table_1.getInputMap();
ActionMap am = table_1.getActionMap();

im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, InputEvent.CTRL_MASK), "pressed");
    am.put("pressed", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int[] columns = table_1.getSelectedColumns();
                int[] rows = table_1.getSelectedRows();
                int selectedRow = table_1.getEditingRow();
                int selectedCol = table_1.getEditingColumn();
                Object value = table_1.getValueAt(selectedRow, selectedCol);

                for(int row:rows){
                    for(int column:columns){
                        table_1.setValueAt(value,row,column);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Want about it isn't working?

Comment: Yes i would like to know why it isn't working and what I have to do to let it work.